# How can I check if a textbox only contains certain characters when a button is pressed

Tags: c#, validation

I am trying to validate a textbox to ensure that it can only contain alphabetic characters and the characters "-" and "'", as it is for a name. I am trying to collect details that can be added into an account, so I want to collect all other fields and then at the end of the form a button is pressed and I would like the validation to be carried in a buttonclick event, instead of a textchanged event. I have tried other ways including using regular expressions but I have had the problem that it if I enter a letter and a number it sees this as valid.

Any help is much appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using a for loop?

Comment: Use a Ragex like `$[A-Z'-]+^` ;).

Comment: Which UI framework are you using ?  Is it a desktop application or it is a web application ?

Answer (score 1):

use Regular Expressions:

```
bool IsValid = Regex.IsMatch(text, "^[a-zA-Z-']+$");
```